# How to generate report(xlsx format) and Qweb Report in odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo-12

I'm working with account-financial-reporting module (OCA).
I want to add tree structure according to Code  :
if account.code = "xxx000" or "yyy000" , then change the line style to bold , 
and get the other codes in ascending order . Example:

```
Code     |             |
-------------------------
 xxx000  |             |
-------------------------
         |xxx001       |
-------------------------
         |xxx003       |
-------------------------
yyy000   |             |
-------------------------
         |yyy002       |
-------------------------
         |yyy005       |
-------------------------

   def _generate_report_content(self, workbook, report):
        if not report.show_partner_details:
            # Display array header for account lines
            self.write_array_header()

    # For each account
    for account in report.account_ids.filtered(lambda a: not a.hide_line):
        if not report.show_partner_details:
            # Display account lines
            self.write_line(account, 'account')
```

Any help please ?

Comment: `format` is applied in [write_line](https://github.com/OCA/account-financial-reporting/blob/12.0/account_financial_report/report/abstract_report_xlsx.py#L196) method?

Comment: @Kenly    yes , format is applied in write_line method .

Comment: Did you try to make changes there?

Comment: How Can I do it with Qweb Report ? I add this condition :

 `<div>
        <t t-if="'000' in line.code">
           <strong><t t-att-style="style" t-raw="line.code"/></strong></t>
        <t t-else ="'000' not in line.code" >                                      
            <t t-raw="line.code" style="font-weight: bold"/>
         </t>
  </div>`

But , my problem is how to add new column for translation if there are codes to have the exact tree structure ?? Thanks.